# Why did Vanessa not connect Lily with Brona Croft?

Tags: penny-dreadful

How does Vanessa not recognize Lily as being clearly the same person as Brona Croft? Yes, she only met her once but she took a very keen interest in her as she was intrigued to see the woman that had captured Ethan's heart.

Her failure to recognize Lily (in the way Dorian Gray did *instantly*) seems like a continuity error. **Is there an explanation?**

Answer (score 3):

Let us take it this way :
Someone (A) you met briefly and liked died. 
Sometime later you are introduced to a person (B) who closely resembles A, though has different mannerisms, a different accent, a different name, and different circumstances. You are open minded but not immediately aware of a way that it would be possible for A or any one to have been ressurected in such a manner as to become as B or any one else.
Do you assume that B must be A, simply because of their striking resemblance? I personally would not assume this under those circumstances. It is believable that Vanessa does not assume this of Lily either -- importantly because she is not aware of the precise nature of Victor's work. If she were aware of the true manner of his labours, she would be a fool not to see the strong possibly that Lily is physically Brona.

Comment: Plus they don't ugly-down the beautiful actors to the degree that an accurate depiction of a low-priced drug-addled prostitute with TB living in squalor would.  The contrast between her circumstances before and after would have a pretty big effect on her appearance, as well.  Another clue is how she only remembered the Creature as the orderly in the mental hospital after extensive hypnosis.